# Paypal redirect issue in iPad

Tags: ruby, paypal-sandbox

I have an issue on iPad, I am using Paypal sandbox with my Ruby code. Which is a SOAP call to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/.  When I pay from my iPad, it redirects to my return url but as a Get request. But when I pay from my laptop/window/ubantu machine, it redirects as a POST request. I am unable to understand why is it happening.
Please help me in this.

Comment: Which PayPal API are you using?  Are you using NVP or SOAP style APIs? (There are many ways to integrate with PayPal.) Can you include a re-create?

Comment: It is a SOAP call to sandbox account

Comment: And the rest? PayPal has lots integration approaches: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/